# Passing a Structure to a Generic Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I am tyring to use a generic linked list for my project. For reference, I am following this implementation made by [David Muto](http://pseudomuto.com/development/2013/05/02/implementing-a-generic-linked-list-in-c.html). My aim is to parse user-information(user-name and other details) from a plain text file and load these into my linked-list.

```
typedef struct {
char *user_name;
char *password;
char *friends;
}user_info;
```

Here is the code-flow.

```
list users;
list_new(&users,sizeof(user_info*),free_users);
init_server(&users);
list_for_each(&users,iterate_users);
list_destroy(&users);
```

Parsing is done in `init_server()`. In it the user_info struct is allocated and reference to tokens are copied into it. After this I make a call to `list_append()`.

#### list_append()

```
void list_append(list *list, void *element){
listNode *node = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
node->data = malloc(list->elementSize);  
node->next=NULL;
memcpy(node->data,element,list->elementSize);

if(list->logicalLength == 0){
  list->head = list->tail = node;
}else {
  list->tail->next=node;
  list->tail=node;
}

list->logicalLength++;
}
```

#### Problem

Only the username reference is present in all the elements in the list. Here are the values
of the element( structure reference passed to `list_append()`) and the head of the the list after the call returns.

```
(gdb) print *(user_info*)element
$31 = {username = 0x603270 "trudy", password =
0x603290"areyouthereyet",friends=0x6032b0 "bob;alice\n"}    

(gdb) print *(user_info *)list->head->data
$36 = {username = 0x603270 "trudy", password = 0x0, friends = 0x0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
sizeof(user_info*)
```

should be this:

```
sizeof(user_info)
```

You want the size of the struct itself, not the size of a pointer to it. Right now, your `memcpy()` call is not copying all the data as a result.

Similarly, `listNode *node = malloc(sizeof(listNode))` should probably be `listNode *node = malloc(sizeof(*node))` for the same reason. I'm assuming `node->data = malloc(list->elementSize);` will be correct once you're passing the right size to `list_new()`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the list->elementSize set to?

Another potential issue:

You're storing pointers to the memory where the strings are.
Suppose you parse a character string then store a pointer.
Later if the string is deallocated the pointer will be aimed at whatever gets placed there later. It will be very difficult to debug. Make sure your strings remain during the time you use your list.

Comment: I am setting the wrong elementSize for the list. About storing pointers to strings: right now , I strdup the tokens I grab during the parsing and free them once I don't need them.

Comment: If you free them and then try to use the pointer it will point to freed memory. It may still contain the strings or it may not. It just depends on if another part of the program allocated memory and reused the same area. Glad you got it fixed